# Can Report Builder 3.0 work if only .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is installed on Windows 7 client PC?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, reportbuilder3.0

This [page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116) mentions that Report Builder 3.0 system requirements need component Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Our users don't have the .net 3.5 framework nor the corresponding SP1 installed on their Windows 7s. I have the .NET Framework 4 (Client Profile as well as Extended) installed on my Windows 7.

I'd like to know (or someone can point out) if only having the Framework 4 Client Profile would be enough for our users to create reports in Report Builder 3.0 and be able to connect to our SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4):

just before hitting the report builder 3.0 make sure the browser(IE) is set to compatibility view,which is present in the TOOLS bar.I have tried on both WIN 7 & WIN 8.it will definitively work.